Low-Collision Abbreviation For Public Key Hex Representation
I am writing an application where each client generates its own public/private key pair that uniquely identifies it to other clients. Clients are using the Web Crypto API to generate ECDSA P-384 keys. The hex representation of a public key is 194 characters long, making some WebSocket messages longer than needed.
So, I want to have a shorter representation of that key. The idea is that clients would receive an object containing all clients on their instance, allowing them to translate the abbreviation back into the public key.
My current idea, inspired by Git, is the first 7 characters of the SHA-1 hash of the public key. Would this give me a sufficiently low chance of collisions to be acceptable for this use case?

Each share instance will have fewer than 1000 (really 100) clients
There will be around 1000 instances over the course of a year

Example Code:
async function getPrefix(key: CryptoKey) {
 const buffer = await crypto.subtle.exportKey("raw", publicKey);
 const digest = await crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-1", buffer);
 const hex = Array.from(new Uint8Array(digest), (x) =>
    x.toString(16).padStart(2, "0")
  ).join("");
 return hex.slice(0, 7);
}


For $n=16^7$ possible short ids, $c=1000$ clients (stated maximum), $i=1000$ instances (stated approximation of the expected value), and assuming random choice of keys thus next to uniformly random short ids, the probability of not having a collision is
$$p=\left(\prod_{0\le j<c}\frac{n-j}n\right)^i=0.156\ldots$$
The numbers are small enough that Wolfram Mathematica handles it fine (Try it online!). In a language restricted to floating point we could also sum the logarithms obtained with $\mathtt{log1p}(-j/n)$ for numerical stability.
So it's quite probable there's a collision, and thus this is not a good idea even under the hypothesis of random choice of keys. Which does not seem a robust hypothesis because there is nothing to prevent the clients from deliberately choosing keys with short ids that they find fun, like BADF00D, increasing the likelihood of collision dramatically; or deliberately cause collisions.

For low probability $\epsilon$ of accidental collision, you want $n\ge c^2i/(2\epsilon)$. For $c=2^{10}$, $i=2^{10}$, $\epsilon=2^{-32}$, that's $\log_2n\ge2\cdot10+10+32-1$ thus a 61-bit hash. Make that 8 bytes, 16 hex characters.
For $k$-bit security against deliberate collision with a fast hash, you want $n\approx2^{2k}$, that is a $2k$-bit hash. For 128-bit security (much less than the target security of P-384) that would be 256 bits (32 bytes, 64 hex characters). Each time we make the hash twice slower/more costly (e.g. by using Argon2 and bumping the workfactor), you can save 2 bits on the hash width.


The hex representation of a public (P-384) key is 194 characters long
I want to have a shorter representation of that key

One needs 385 bits to represent any P-384 key using point compression. That fits 49 bytes. So it's lost a factor of 2 to not using point compression, and another factor of 2 to using hex.
If possible, reconsider using text to represent inherently arbitrary bits or bytes. That's eating bandwidth, memory, and CPU time for conversions, thus dooms humanity faster. Using text has become commonplace for reasons that initially boiled down to human readability, which is a dubious goal when it comes to cryptographic stuff: it adds need for conversion code, parsing, thus bugs. It promotes code [test repair...] habits. I have yet to find a comparative study supporting that it makes inherent economic sense in contexts where (beside developers in debugging attitude) humans neither generate nor read the text-encoded content.

clients would receive an object containing all clients on their instance

Then why not use an index of the client-within-instance in that object?
